# PPTP client on ADSL router

Tags: networking, router, vpn

If my internet connection is done by ADSL, is it possible to configure the router to connect to a VPN by PPTP protocol and all the computers in my home network to be in the same subnetwork that has the IP of the VPN server I am using?

In short: I have ADSL connection and an account to a service such as pureVPN, I need all the devices in the network to have the same external IP as what I choose from pureVPN. Is this possible using a single device? If yes, what model would you recommend? If not, would it work if I connect another router to the ADSL router and connect all devices to the first router, which also connects to VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: I think not.

Longer answer: most VPN providers do not recommend the ADSL client and the VPN client to be on the same device. It may be possible, but it's easier just to connect a router to the ADSL modem (WAN of the router to a LAN output of the modem) and run the VPN client on that router.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible on professional devices (for example Cisco 886 series), besides PPTP other protocols such as IPSec or L2TP could be used.

On consumer grade devices, it really depends on what router and which firmware you are using.

Comment: Yes, that's true, so that's why it's much easier to connect a second router to the ADSL router and run the PPTP client on it. Any DD-WRT router would do.